# Database peformance with joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173726/when-and-why-are-database-joins-expensive)

My company has assigned me a job of improving DB performance.
Earlier developer has written a query having 5 innerjoins.

What is the number of inner joins which can be used without hurting performance ?

Comment: The post I linked to has a comprehensive discussion of joins - in general though, 5 innerjoins using good indexes is not a problem. It really comes down to the old story, when concerned about performance, benchmark to see if there is actually a problem in what you are trying to tune.

Answer (score 7):

JOINs can perform better than alternatives, in specific situations.  And it's not unusual to see that many joins in a normalized database.

JOINs aren't always necessary -- if there aren't references outside of the JOIN for the table, `EXISTS` or `IN` will perform better.  For example:

```
SELECT a.column
  FROM TABLE_A a 
  JOIN TABLE_B b ON b.col = a.col
```

...vs:

```
SELECT a.column
  FROM TABLE_A a 
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                FROM TABLE_B b 
               WHERE b.col = a.col)
```

If the joins are necessary for the resultset, then assess the situation:

- Are there indexes on the foreign keys (the columns used to for the JOIN criteria)?
- Are any of the join criteria requiring functions for JOINs to work.  IE:

  ```
  JOIN table x ON DATE(x.col) = y.column
  ```

  ...because such cases would render an index on `x.col` useless
- Is the data type of the foreign keys as narrow as possible, because the less bytes used to store the value means faster database performance.  IE: VARCHAR(4) vs INT

### Conclusion

It's plausible that denormalizing data can be a performance benefit but it's the very last option to consider after lots of review & testing.

Comment: It's quite easy to demonstrate then IN/EXISTS is better then JOINs if you don't need data from one of the tables. What makes you say this?

Comment: done. Your old first line let down the rest ;-) Quassnoi did a lot on it eg http://explainextended.com/2009/09/30/in-vs-join-vs-exists-oracle/

Comment: @gbn: I need an editor =)  I have all of them bookmarked - Oracle, MySQL (nullable & not), PostgreSQL, and SQL Server :)