# how to design pricing module at database level

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, entity-relationship

I want to model the following scenario in the database:

I have a Package, comprising of independent `Activities` and `Hotel`:

Package P:

- Activities **A1, A2, A3**
- Hotel **H**

`Activities` and `Hotel` are independent entities which have their own price defined at the time of **definition** of entity.

When an entity is **added** to the package, it's price can be changed (only `specific to the package`). Hence, every package would have a unique price for the activities/hotels.

E.g.
`(Defining activities and hotel)`:

```
A1 - 10$
A2 - 20$

H1 - 100$
```

`(Adding activities and hotel to package)`:

```
Package p;
p.addActivity("A1", 15);
p.addActivity("A2", 25);
p.addHotel("H1", 50);

yields => 

p
 - A1 - 15
 - A2 - 25
 - H1 - 50
```

---

Database Side:

**Definition**:

- `Activity`:

  Activity-id, StartDate, EndDate, Price
- `Hotel`:

  Hotel-id, StartDate, EndDate, Price

**After adding to package**

- `Package table`:

Package-id, Hotel-id, Activity-id

- `Package-Activity price table`:

  Package-id, Activity-id, Price  *//package-id and activity-id serve as unique key*
- `Package-Hotel price table`:

  Package-id, Hotel-id, Price    *//package-id and hotel-id serve as unique key*

I need some feedback on the design that I've come up with.
Have I over complicated this ? Is there a simpler/better way to do this ?
Also, as I was writing this, I figured a package can have many Hotels and Activities, so will need to factor that in here.
Have I fragmented this too much since, for each price lookup of an entity I will be performing a join ?

**EDIT**

Found a relevant link on performance with Joins: [When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173726/when-and-why-are-database-joins-expensive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually do need five tables here.

You have *three* entities: activities, hotels, and packages (assuming each package has some data which is not hotel- or activity-related). You have two relationships, both many-to-many, namely package-hotel and package-activity. Each relationship row is annotated with a particular price.

Five tables is the way to go. No, having to do a join is not a problem: it's better than having non-normal data. You can denormalize for performance later **if necessary**.

Comment: I'm a little confused. So, we have 1 table for all activities. Package can contain multiple activities, so I need one-to-many relationship there. I'd assume Package-activities table is the way to go for that. I want to keep a separate table for pricing, so I'd have a Package-activities-price for that as I listed in my question. Correct ?

Comment: @brainydexter: No. First off, a package can contain multiple activities, but a given activity can be in multiple packages. That's a many-to-many relationship. Now, when you have a many-many join table, you don't have to limit yourself to just two fields, so the price can be in that table along with `package_id` and `activity_id`. Why would you keep a separate table for just the prices? It would have to *also* have the IDs in order for you to know to what the price refers.