# What is the maximum number of table joins in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, limit, mariadb

Is the number of table joins in MariaDB 10 limited to 61 [as is the case for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/joins-limits.html) or another number?

(I couldn't find the answer in the [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-documentation/) or by googling).

Comment: Why would it matter? You're not likely to need anything like that number of JOINs in a properly normalized schema!

Comment: Depends on complexity. My previous (£7 million) project hit this problem in a big way and had to use a lot of workarounds.

Comment: Has that query finished running yet?

Comment: Joins don't equal slowness if foreign keys are used. E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173726/when-and-why-are-database-joins-expensive#174047

Comment: If you use multi-table inheritance in Doctrine, this limit is quite easy to hit. Yes, it is usually result of a bad design decision, but you may realize that too late to change that.

Comment: Not necessarily bad design - the limit could potentially be hit in any relational data model that contains a lot of entities given the JPA 2.0 default for `@ManyToOne` mappings is eager loading. The project I was working on ended up changing all `@ManyToOne`s to use lazy loading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MariaDB has the same maximum number of 61 tables in a join.

This query

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT(10) NOT NULL);
select *
from t a01 join t a02 join t a03 join t a04 join t a05 join t a06 join t a07 join t a08 join t a09 join t a10
join t a11 join t a12 join t a13 join t a14 join t a15 join t a16 join t a17 join t a18 join t a19 join t a20
join t a21 join t a22 join t a23 join t a24 join t a25 join t a26 join t a27 join t a28 join t a29 join t a30
join t a31 join t a32 join t a33 join t a34 join t a35 join t a36 join t a37 join t a38 join t a39 join t a40
join t a41 join t a42 join t a43 join t a44 join t a45 join t a46 join t a47 join t a48 join t a49 join t a50
join t a51 join t a52 join t a53 join t a54 join t a55 join t a56 join t a57 join t a58 join t a59 join t a60
join t a61 join t a62;
```

yields `ERROR 1116 (HY000): Too many tables; MariaDB can only use 61 tables in a join`.

Comment: Good answer, thanks for testing this out. Out of interest (and for posterity), which version of MariaDB were you using?

Comment: I was using MariaDB 10.0.11.