# Performance of joins on multi-million-row tables

Tags: mysql, database, performance, join, database-design

I need to give my website users the ability to select their country, province and city. So I want to display a list of countries, then a list of provinces in the selected country, then a list of cities in the selected province (I don't want any other UI solution for now). Of course, every name must be in the user's language, so I need additional tables for the translations.

Let's focus on the case of the cities. Here are the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `province_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_city_province` (`province_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_city_province` FOREIGN KEY (`province_id`) REFERENCES `province` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `city_translation` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `locale_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_city_translation_city` (`city_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_city_translation_locale` (`locale_id`),
  KEY `idx_city_translation_city_locale` (`city_id`,`locale_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_city_translation_city` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `city` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_city_translation_locale` FOREIGN KEY (`locale_id`) REFERENCES `locale` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The `city` table contains 4 millions rows and the `city_translation` table  4 millions × the number of the languages available on my website. This is 12 millions now. If in the future I want to support 10 languages, it will be 40 millions...

So I am wondering: is it a bad idea (performance wise) to work with a table of this size, or is a good index (here on the join fields, `city_id` and `locale_id`) sufficient to make the size not matter?

If not, what are the common solutions used to solve this specific --but I guess common-- problem? I'm only interested in performance. I'm ok to denormalize if necessary, or even to use other tools if they are more appropriate (ElasticSearch?).

Comment: The accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173726/when-and-why-are-database-joins-expensive?rq=1) has some good info

Comment: Paris is "Paris" in several languages. You could implement a fall-back system where if city.name doesn't have translation then use alternate

Comment: "So I am wondering: is it a bad idea (performance wise) to work with a table of this size, or is a good index here on the join fields?"  Why don't you try it, and let us know what the results are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of `id` in city_translations.  Instead have `PRIMARY KEY(city_id, locale_id)`.  With InnoDB, this may double the speed because of cutting out an unnecessary step in the `JOINs`.  And you can shrink the disk footprint by also removing the two indexes starting with `city_id`.

Do you think you will go beyond 16M cities?  I doubt it.  So save one byte by changing (in all tables) `city_id` to `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`.

Save 3 bytes by changing `locale_id` to `TINYINT UNSIGNED`.

Those savings are multiplied by the number of columns and indexes mentioning them.

How big are the tables (GB)?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM is there?  See if you can make that setting bigger than the total table size and yet no more than 70% of *available* memory.  (That's the only "tunable" that is worth checking.)

I hope you have a default of `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` for the sake of Chinese users.  (But that is another story.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, @Rick. However, my question was about wether it is or not a bad idea to work with such big tables or if it is generally better to try to do it another way. What I need are elements to go for one model design or another, criteria to weigh the pros and cons, etc. Or even something so basic as: "from x records up, forget it" ;-) I would love to read your advices on these points in your answer.

Comment: "For a billion records up, it gets exciting."  No, I don't say "forget it".  What I failed to say is "your 40M rows is fine".  I simply launched into listing some tips on making it work better.  What you have described (so far) is moderately bulky, but 'simple'.