# MYSQL who are my JOINS appear to make a query faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, optimization, database-optimization

I am trying to improve the performance of a query using a "materialized view" to optimize away joins.  The first query below is the original, which employs joins.  The second is the query written against a table i generated which includes all the joined data (the equivalent of a materialized view).  They both return the same result set.  Unfortunalatey, somehow, the second query is MUCH slower when handling a very long set of input ids (the IN clause).  I don't understand how that could be!!!!  Executing all the joins has to have a fair amount of overheat that is saved by the "materialized view", right?

```
SELECT 
        clinical_sample.INTERNAL_ID AS "internalId",
        sample.STABLE_ID AS "sampleId",
        patient.STABLE_ID AS "patientId",
        clinical_sample.ATTR_ID AS "attrId",
        cancer_study.CANCER_STUDY_IDENTIFIER AS "studyId", 
        clinical_sample.ATTR_VALUE AS "attrValue"
         
        FROM clinical_sample
        INNER JOIN sample ON clinical_sample.INTERNAL_ID = sample.INTERNAL_ID
        INNER JOIN patient ON sample.PATIENT_ID = patient.INTERNAL_ID
        INNER JOIN cancer_study ON patient.CANCER_STUDY_ID = 
                              cancer_study.CANCER_STUDY_ID
         WHERE cancer_study.CANCER_STUDY_IDENTIFIER = 'xxxxx' 
         AND  sample.STABLE_ID IN
                     ('P-0068343-T02-IM7' , 'P-0068353-T01-IM7' ,
                      'P-0068363-T01-IM7' , 'P-0068364-T01-IM7'  )
         AND clinical_sample.ATTR_ID IN
                (
                    'CANCER_TYPE'
                );
```

```
SELECT   
        internalId,
        sampleId,
      patientId,
       attrId,
        studyId, 
        attrValue
         
        FROM test
         WHERE 
         sampleId IN ('P-0068343-T02-IM7' , 'P-0068353-T01-IM7' ,
                      'P-0068363-T01-IM7' , 'P-0068364-T01-IM7'  )
         AND studyId = 'xxxxx' 
         AND attrId = 'CANCER_TYPE';
```

Update: I did notice in Workbench report that the query with joins seems to scan far fewer rows.  About 829k vs ~2400k for the second, joinless query.  So having joins seems to actually be a major optimization somehow.  I have index in sampleId, studyId, attrId and composite of all three.
Both table "test" and "clinical_sample" have the same number of rows.

Comment: Add a composite index on `(studyId, attrId, sampleId)` to the `test` table.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar it has exactly that index already.  Also individual indexes on the columns.   I did notice in Workbench that the query with joins seems to scan far fewer rows.  About 829k vs ~2400k for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see what the `PRIMARY KEY` of each table is.

Some of these indexes are likely to help:

```
clinical_sample:  INDEX(ATTR_ID, INTERNAL_ID,  ATTR_VALUE)
sample:  INDEX(STABLE_ID, INTERNAL_ID,  PATIENT_ID)
patient:  INDEX(INTERNAL_ID,  STABLE_ID, CANCER_STUDY_ID)
cancer_study:  INDEX(CANCER_STUDY_IDENTIFIER, CANCER_STUDY_ID)
```

I agree with Barmar's `INDEX(studyId, attrId, sampleId)` for the materialized view.

> I have index in sampleId, studyId, attrId and composite of all three.

Let's see the `EXPLAIN`.  It may show that it is using your index just on `(sampleId)` when it *should* be using the composite index.

Also put the `IN` column *last*, not first, regardless of cardinality.  More precisely, put `=` columns *first* in a composite index.

Comment: These indexes are on the original tables, they have no effect on the performance of the materialized view.

Comment: Right.  The mystery is why the materalized view would be MUCH slower.

Comment: @Barmar - How could you tell that those indexes were on the original tables??

Comment: I mean you're telling him what indexes should be on the original tables. But he's not working with the original tables any more, so they don't matter.

Comment: These indexes would affect the performance of creating the materialized view in the first place, but they don't matter when querying the view.

Comment: OK, I am providing info that was not requested.

Comment: A little more info: it appears to be only using the index for attrId, NOT the compound index.  I deleted all indexes (on the test table) except the compound index.  5 times slower.  So it appears it's just not employing the compound index for some reason.

Comment: @CpnAhab - Are you referring to `clinical_sample` or the View?  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  I think you were right to get rid of `INDEX(a)` when you also have `INDEX(a,b)`.  The former is redundant, yet the Optimizer seems to prefer it because it is "smaller".

Comment: Appears to not use the compound index at all.   I even attempted to force it   FROM test USE INDEX(total)   

@RickJames this is explains:

'1','SIMPLE','test',NULL,'ALL','total',NULL,NULL,NULL,'14360648','0.50','Using where'.

Comment: @CpnAhab - Which `SELECT` gave that `EXPLAIN`?  Let's see the full definition of the materialized view.  That is, please provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table that was created from that view.  (MySQL has no "materialized" views, only views that you materialize into a table.)

Comment: @RickJames Here is a DESCRIBE on the table.  Yes, I use "materialized view" conceptually.  The table is very simple.   In general would you agree that it is possible for a JOIN strategy to vastly outperform a query on a simple table of denormalized data?  Does that make any sense?

'id','int(11)','NO','PRI',NULL,'auto_increment'
'internalId','int(11)','NO','',NULL,''
'sampleId','varchar(50)','NO','MUL',NULL,''
'patientId','varchar(50)','NO','',NULL,''
'attrId','varchar(255)','NO','',NULL,''
'studyId','varchar(255)','YES','',NULL,''
'attrValue','varchar(255)','NO','',NULL,''

Comment: `DESCRIBE` is less descriptive than `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  For one thing, `DESCRIBE` does not clearly identify all the indexes.  Though perhaps it does say that you have not added Barmar's index.

Answer (score 0):

Food for thought: [When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173726/when-and-why-are-database-joins-expensive?rq=1)
this leads me to believe that normalized tables with indexes could actually be faster than my denormalized attempt (materialized view).